# Laravel 5.0: How to save multiple inputs of rows in the same column of database?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I am an absolute beginner of Laravel and dealing with a certain problem.
English is not my first language, so if this post does not make sense to you or you need more information, please leave comments.

I would like to insert multiple data inputs to a single column of a database table.

I made a page with a table in it. For example, the instructor will leave comments on both the first and second row for "instructor comment" column.

However, I have difficulty finding a way to do so.
I am dealing with the error below.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**create.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'logs']) !!}

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="weeks">
      {!! Form::selectRange('weeks[]', 1, 17) !!}
    </td>
    <td class="work_description">
      {!! Form::textarea('work_description[]', null) !!}
    </td>
    <td class="instructor_comments">
      {!! Form::textarea('instructor_comment[]', null) !!}
    </td>
    <td class="status">
      {!! Form::text('status[]', null) !!}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="weeks">
      {!! Form::selectRange('weeks[]', 1, 17) !!}
    </td>
    <td class="work_description">
      {!! Form::textarea('work_description[]', null) !!}
    </td>
    <td class="instructor_comments">
      {!! Form::textarea('instructor_comment[]', null) !!}
    </td>
    <td class="status">
      {!! Form::text('status[]', null) !!}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**create_logs_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('logs', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('weeks');
        $table->text('work_description');
        $table->text('instructor_comments');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**Error::**

`preg_replace()`: Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Comment: Your error is occurring where you have call to preg_replace() somewhere in your code, and it isn't the code you've pasted above.  Do you have code for a controller that takes the information from the form and saves it to the database that you could paste?

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you can add some mutators that can help:

```
public function setInstructorCommentsAttribute( $value )
{
  $this->attributes['instructor_comments'] = json_encode( $value );
}

public function getInstructorCommentsAttribute()
{
  $type = json_decode( $this->attributes['instructor_comments'] );
  return $type;
}
```

The `setInstructorCommentsAttribute` will convert the Input array into a JSON object and save that to the database. The `getInstructorCommentsAttribute` will then decode the JSON object back into an array for you to use in your code.

Add this code to your `logs` model.